# Set border on first table row, w/o using a ID or class

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I am trying to style a web app that we don't have the source code too.

So I drilled down into the DOM, but right now the bottom border is being set on ALL the rows, I need only the first row.

```
#tableID tbody tr td table tbody tr
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc; 
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about supporting IE6:

```
#tableID tbody tr td table tbody:first-child
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#tableID tbody tr td table tbody tr:first-child { }
```

Should select the first chidld according to the CSS 2 selector specification.

[See here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) for some information which browsers select the selectors.

Comment: need to apply it to the th/td directly no the tr so:
`#tableID tbody tr td table tbody > tr:first-child td, #tableID tbody tr td table tbody > tr:first-child th { }`

Comment: prodogitalson, yup that did it!